# Android Studio Emulator: Emulator terminated with exit code 22

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

My emulator was working fine until last night, now when I try to launch a device I get: `The emulator process for AVD Pixel_6_Pro_API_33 has terminated.` All I remember doing was changing the emulator from launching in android studio into launching in a separate window then changing that back. After that it stopped working. When I look at the log this is the error message:

```
2023-04-22 09:51:13,657 [ 701415] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code 22
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code 22
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:182)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorProcessHandler$ConsoleListener.onTextAvailable(EmulatorProcessHandler.kt:89)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:222)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessTerminatedListener.processTerminated(ProcessTerminatedListener.java:54)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor172.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$2.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:248)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.processTerminated(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.lambda$notifyTerminated$2(ProcessHandler.java:206)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$TasksRunner.execute(ProcessHandler.java:281)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:189)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyProcessTerminated(ProcessHandler.java:185)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseProcessHandler.onOSProcessTerminated(BaseProcessHandler.java:61)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$1.lambda$startNotified$0(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:98)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$0(ProcessWaitFor.java:45)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:212)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessWaitFor.lambda$new$1(ProcessWaitFor.java:23)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2023-04-22 09:51:13,672 [ 701430] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2  Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
2023-04-22 09:51:13,672 [ 701430] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - JDK: 11.0.15; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o.
2023-04-22 09:51:13,672 [ 701430] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 33 - OS: Windows 11
```

I can't find any info on exit code 22. I tried freeing up more disc space (30 GB) and it didn't change anything. I tried making a new virtual device with more ram and storage space but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem though I don't understand why its an issue in the first place. Upon more inspection I tried manually running the emulator through the CMD and received the following error:
`Could not launch 'C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe': Invalid argument` 
I tried looking it up but never found the exact error. I tried running android studio as administrator and it worked, not sure why but it was working before normally without admin.